# How can I get this value in Java Class?

Tags: java, zk, zk-grid

I have a form built with zk.
In this part :

```
<template name="model:group">            
            <group label="@load(each)" value="@load(each)" onClick="@command('viewGraph')"/>      
        </template>
```

I call method **viewGraph()** and i want that this value is sent to this method.
In **JavaScript** i should have made this:

```
onClick="function(parameter);"
```

In this case I don't know how to do.

Also, if i can't set an id on label because label is in a cycle so, it must have 1 different id.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `group` inside of `viewGraph`, write

```
 <group label="@load(each)" value="@load(each)" onClick="@command('viewGraph', self=self)"/>

public void viewGraph(@BindingParam("self") Integer self){
//your code here
}
```

See [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Advanced/Parameters) for more info.